# formats.h file containing WAV file format info

Tags: c, linux, wav, alsa

I am trying to make a prog which can record voice and store it in digital audio format on LINUX using ALSA. (currently using Ubuntu). 
While looking for some help on net, I found this code from [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=456462)

```
#include "formats.h"
...
...
  WaveChunkHeader      wch, ch = {WAV_FMT,16};
  WaveHeader           h;
  WaveFmtBody          f;
  wch.type     = WAV_DATA;
...
...
```

However, I don't have "formats.h" header file on my system. Any one know from where(which dev pkg) I can get this header file (containing audio file format related info)?

Thanks,
Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be in the alsa-utils package, subdirectory aplay:

http://alsa-utils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.17/formats_8h-source.html